# Can geographical notifications be reset?

Tags: subnautica

While exploring the ocean, you'll periodically receive notifications about the surrounding area when you approach certain areas for the first time.

For example, one notification

> tells you about a nearby cave system having fossilized remains.

A document I came across later in the game mentions several of these areas as places to search for important points of interest. The problem is, I want to find these areas again and have absolutely no clue where they are.

Is there a way to reset certain notifications to trigger again when I'm near the right area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Dialogue) is a list of the voice-overs with there specific triggers.

In cases similar to your example **the dialogue is triggered by entering a new [biome](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Dialogue#Biomes) for the first time** (the notification you provide is heard when entering [Lost River](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Lost_River)).
It doesn't matter from what point you enter that biome.

All the geographical notifications are also listed on [their respective Fandom pages](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Biomes).

I don't think there is a way to reinstate the triggering of the notifications (I tried removing the *CellsCache* folder but, not unsurprisingly, that doesn't reinitialize them).